# How to use gzip_static and a reverse proxy caching setup simultaneously for dynamically generated content?

Tags: nginx, compression, gzip, reverse-proxy

I am confused by https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/#sending-compressed-files which reads:

> Note that the gzip_static directive does not enable on-the-fly
> compression. It merely uses a file compressed beforehand by any
> compression tool. To compress content (and not only static content) at
> runtime, use the gzip directive.

That makes it sound like I have to compress static files outside of nginx.

Can nginx compress dynamically generated content (say an HTML file generated by PHP) and cache both of them in a reverse proxy setup?

Serving the .gz version of the file to any browser that declares they can accept it, and the uncompressed version of the file to any browser who doesn't?

I am just trying to avoid nginx compressing dynamically generated content (that is already cached for the next hour) over and over again every time a new client visits the same page?

Or maybe it does that by default and I'm not understanding something?